# Powershell, registry and wildcards, oh my

Tags: powershell, registry, wildcard

Given...

```
HKLM\Software\   
  KeyName
    Property_1
    Property_2
    Property_[0-1] 
  Key*Name
    Property_1
    Property_2
    Property_[0-1]   
  Key@Name
    Property_1
    Property_2
    Property_[0-1]
```

I can use

```
Get-Item -path:"Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Key*Name"
```

which will return `KeyName`, `Key*Name` and `Key@Name`, while

```
Get-Item -literalPath:"Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Key*Name"
```

will return just `Key*Name`. So far, so good. I can use -path or -literalPath as needed to either search for a key with wildcards or not. But properties pose a problem.

```
Get-ItemProperty -path:"Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\KeyName" -name:"Prop_[0-9]"
```

works as expected and returns `Prop_1` & `Prop_2` from the `KeyName` key. And

```
Get-ItemProperty -literalPath:"Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\KeyName" -name:"Prop_[0-9]"
```

works as expected and returns just `Prop_[0-9]` from the same key. But it all fails apart when you need to use a wildcard to find properties, in a path that includes a wildcard character as a literal in the key path. So...

```
Get-ItemProperty -path:"Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Key*Name" -name:"Prop_[0-9]"
```

returns `Prop_1` & `Prop_2` from all three keys. Not the desired behavior at all.

I had hoped to be able to filter on `PSPath` using -`literalPath' but this

```
Get-ItemProperty -literalPath:"Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Key*Name" -name:"Prop_[0-9]" | where {$_.PSPath -match [RegEx]::Escape("Key*Name")}
```

does not return the correct properties. It seems that a `-literalPath` means a literal name also. So I tried filtering on `PSPath` and `Name` like so

```
Get-ItemProperty -literalPath:"Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Key*Name" -name:"Prop_[0-9]" | where {(($_.PSPath -match [RegEx]::Escape("Key*Name")) -and ($_.Name -match "Prop_[0-9]"))}
```

But that doesn't work because once you actually get real properties, they are no longer a .NET type, they have been shat into a `PSCustomObject`.
And that is starting to get so complicated I wonder if there is a better way to proceed.  I should note that the ultimate goal here is to get both a literal path and a list of literal property names, so that I can move, copy or delete the properties. So, given a path of `Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Key*Name` and a name of `Prop_[0-9]` I will eventually want to, for example, delete

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Key*Name\Prop_1
```

&

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Key*Name\Prop_2
```

but not

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Key*Name\Prop_[0-9]
```

EDIT: Based on the answer from @Tomalak I have simplified a bit, to simply get back a list of property names. That looks like this

```
$keyPath = "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Key*Name"
$propExpr = "Prop_[0-9]"
((Get-Item -literalPath:$keyPath | Get-ItemProperty).PSObject.Properties | Where-Object Name -Match $propExpr | ForEach-Object {$_.Name})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get a registry key by literal path and filter its properties by regex match

```
$keyPath = "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Key*Name"
$propExpr = "Prop_[0-9]"

Get-Item -literalPath $keyPath -PipelineVariable key | Get-ItemProperty | ForEach-Object {
    $_.PSObject.Properties | Where-Object Name -Match $propExpr | ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            key = $key.Name
            prop = $_.Name
            value = $_.Value
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of the `$key.Name` you can of course return the actual `$key` if that's more convenient for your task.

Comment: I had just managed to get something to work, namely `Get-Item -literalPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Key*Name\' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty property | Where {$_ -match "Prop_[0-9]"}`. Now I have a more general purpose approach. Time to integrate. For anyone else wanting to make it work, `-literalPath` should be `$keyPath` not `$key`, and `$keyPath` needs to start with `Registry::` or `HKLM:`.

Comment: @Gordon You're right, those were oversights when I translated my testing code. Fixed.

Comment: No worries. It was actually really good for me to need to really understand  your approach to make it work. Best way to learn. :) Really happy to have a better approach in general for dealing with `PSCustomObject` as a return type too.

Comment: @Gordon There's always more than one way with PowerShell.

Comment: VERY true, that. :)