# Get-ItemProperty with wildcard; results as array

Tags: powershell, registry

Given a registry key of

```
registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TestKey
```

and text properties called `TestString1`, `TestString2` & `NotValid`

I can use

```
Get-ItemProperty -path:"registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TestKey" -name:"TestString*"
```

and I will get back

```
TestString1  : One
TestString2  : Two
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TestKey
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE
PSChildName  : TestKey
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

But what I want is an array of just the two properties who's names match the wildcard.

```
Get-ItemProperty -path:"registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TestKey" -name:"TestString*" | Get-Member
```

produces

```
Name         MemberType   Definition                                                                           
----         ----------   ----------                                                                           
Equals       Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                       
GetHashCode  Method       int GetHashCode()                                                                    
GetType      Method       type GetType()                                                                       
ToString     Method       string ToString()                                                                    
PSChildName  NoteProperty string PSChildName=TestKey                                                           
PSParentPath NoteProperty string PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE  
PSPath       NoteProperty string PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TestKey
PSProvider   NoteProperty ProviderInfo PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry                           
TestString1  NoteProperty string TestString1=One                                                               
TestString2  NoteProperty string TestString2=Two
```

which makes me think

```
Get-ItemProperty -path:"registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TestKey" -name:"TestString*" | Where-Object ({$_.Name -like "TestString*"})
```

should do what I want, but it actually returns nothing. What am I missing here?

EDIT: OK, this is weird. And I guess typical Microsoft "thinking". If I actually have a property called `TestString*`, which is a perfectly valid name, because Microsoft is never consistent, the code above returns all three, plus the other stuff. But, if I change the `-Path` to `-LiteralPath`, then I only get the one `-Name`. Which is... crazy. I have never seen any documentation saying that `-LiteralPath` also makes `-Name` behave like `-LiteralName`.

Comment: Hi, It looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69986542/20473839) may help. You'll just need to create a list and add each pscustom object to it.